# How can i populate my array of passengerIDs in cloud firestore from my flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I created a list of passengerIDs but now I am not able to access them in order to add/update a passengerIDs everytime a user is accepted to a ride

Here is my code

```
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("tripsStatus")
        .doc("${request.tripID}/passengerIDs")
        .update({"${int.parse(seat) - int.parse(data)}": request.userID});
```

[And my cloud firestore path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0skcj.jpg)

I tried to update everytime the list when a user requested to join the ride but it's not working it also gives me the error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but tripsStatus/1686505092901977/passengerIDs has 3

Answer (score 1):

Your error means that you're not updating a document, you need to provide the documentID you want to edit/update.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("tripsStatus")
        .doc("${request.tripID}/passengerIDs/${myDocumentID}") // you should add your document ID here 
        .update({"${int.parse(seat) - int.parse(data)}": request.userID});
```